# React: Storing functional component in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I'd like to render a different child component depending on which button has been clicked:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Bold = ({ text }) => (
    <b>{text}</b>
);

const Italic = ({ text }) => (
    <i>{text}</i>
);

export default function App() {
    const [Component, setComponent] = useState();

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => setComponent(Bold)}>
                Bold
            </button>
            <button
                onClick={() => setComponent(Italic)}
            >
                Italic
            </button>
            {Component && (
                <Component text="I love  more than life!" />
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

I was pretty sure this would work - I set my state item to component's function and render it. But it throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'text' of '_ref' as it is undefined.

I checked if it would work without any props in children components, but no - it gives another error when there are no props:

> Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: . Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?

I don't quite understand why it's happening, but I found a workaround. Instead of setting my state value directly like this:

```
<button onClick={() => setComponent(Bold)}>
```

I'm setting it through a setter function:

```
<button onClick={() => setComponent(() => Bold)}>
```

It works correctly after that change, but can someone explain why is this happening? Is having a component *unpacked* somewhere in the template causing problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `setState` has two forms.

One where it accepts some object and one that it accepts a function which can work with existing state and returns the new state.

Now, when you pass a component reference, you are actually passing a function to it, and so `setState` assumes it is the second form, and tries to execute the function in order to get the updated state.

The workaround, as you have found out on your own, is to use the second form, passing a function that when executed will return the component you want.

Comment: Oh right! I haven't thought of that! Thanks so much.